# How to extract svg image width and height using php from an simplexmlfunction?

Tags: php, xml, svg

I have svg image need to get the image height and width. But i am not getting the exact image widht and height of svg. I am using php function to extract.

Original widht and height is 82 * 90 px. how to set it in the svg file actualy it is a clipart file. i need to load with original image width and height.

```
simplexml_load_file($file)

output: 
 SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [width] => 0.908528in [height] => 0.999992in [version] => 1.0 ...............)
```

Comment: Looks like the width and height are in _inches_. There's no way to say how many pixels and inch is.

Comment: could you tell me how to extract the value of viewbox width andheight Array ( [viewBox] => 0 0 100 100 )

Comment: I am probably very late for the party, but using `explode(' ', $viewBox);` could do the trick and result in an array with four elements. Just remember to cast the value to string. Something like `$svg = $simplexml_load_file($file); $viewBoxParts = explode(' ', $svg['viewBox']);` or `$viewBoxParts = explode(' ', (string)$svg->attributes()->viewBox);`. Please note the cast used in the second case.